# Rails app crashes when config.eager_load=true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails application and an Engine.

When i have config.eager_load= true in my environments/production.rb the app crashes giving the following error in the engine

```
FATAL: ActionView::Template::Error(undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<#<Class:0x00000005812fe0>:0x00000005811e88>)
 /var/www/rack_apps/manager/shared/vendor_bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/authorization_engine-0.1.0.SNAPSHOT.20140407182910/app/views/authorization_engine/authorizations/new.html.haml:26:in `__var_www_rack_apps_manager_shared_vendor_bundle_ruby_______gems_authorization_engine_______________________________app_views_authorization_engine_authorizations_new_html_haml__268041456534634533_46121540'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_with_layout'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
```

But the same above seems to work if i set the config.eager_load = false

Is this normal ? ... I know you shouldn't be setting eager_load to false in production. Is there a way not to eager load the engine or have i got the entire concept wrong ?

I know it says undefined variable current_user but it picks it up perfectly when i run locally . Any suggestions or ideas would be awesome .Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to put <code>:require => false</code> to your engine in the Gemfile of the main app. By doing this, your gem would only be loaded when required instead of at boot time.

Comment: doing that gives a problem(uninitialized constant {engine name}) in the initializer of the main app

Comment: Where did you expect `current_user` to be defined?  i.e. where is `current_user` defined when you're running locally (with `eager_load = false`)?

Comment: since you are all serious (add a bounty etc) about this question, consider creating a minimal environment where the error is reproduced and share it with us so that we could try the solutions before posting.

Comment: Which gem is it you are using? Imho the initialization code of the gem (engine) is wrong. Also: when do you get this error? During boot or when rendering something?

Comment: It's hard to say whats wrong with your engine without source code of it.

Comment: Are you running in `production` mode locally?  If `current_user` is a devise variable, is `devise` in you engine's Gemfile as well as the main application?  The bottom line is there's not nearly enough information here to help you. We're reduced to guesswork.  E.g. this isn't the full stack trace, I assume...

Comment: I do have the same issue with different error , when set it to true I am getting "/home/ratnakar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@glimpse/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/debug_helper.rb:25:in `debug': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
" , I am not sure why this is happening to me

Answer (score 0):

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

The official documentation says: 
config.eager_load when true, eager loads all registered config.eager_load_namespaces. This includes your application, engines, Rails frameworks and any other registered namespace.

To answer that question correct we need to know what are you using for sessions, like devise gem or something. But I guess you use some gem for it and if you say that locally your application running without errors, so maybe there is difference in your gem versions locally and on server? You could update gem and it broke something for example. So I advise you to start with this.